# Is it possible that $x\in y$ and $y\in x$ in ZF?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In **ZF**, is it possible that $x\in y$ and $y\in x$? I don't know much about set theory, thanks for answers.

Comment: Despite the question being clear enough from the title, please avoid posting a question only in the title. Titles are for titles, the question go in the body (it's fine to post it both in the body and the title, if it's that short).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If that were the case, the set $z=\lbrace x,y \rbrace$ would contradict the [axiom of foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). This argument also shows that in ZFC you can have no cycles.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks!